# Run specific focused Kiwi 'context' or 'it' element from AppCode?

Tags: objective-c, testing, kiwi, appcode

Often when developing or fixing broken test you need to focus only on one. Is it possible to run only one specific Kiwi **context** or **it** element from JetBrains AppCode (not whole spec)? And if so, how to create configuration to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible yet. Please subscribe to a corresponding [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-6523) on AppCode tracker to keep up to date.

Comment: It's possible with other frameworks such as Specta (http://cocoadventures.org/post/119882286349/focus-on-a-spec)